# Can we estimate or quantify Experimental uncertainty from computational uncertainty?

Tags: soft-question

Causes of Experimental uncertainty can range from limited accuracy of the equipment to variation of environmental conditions. Is there a way to address these experimental uncertainty through model of computation uncertainity? In other words is there any common cause of computational uncertainty and experimental uncertainty?

EDIT: The computational experiments that is output of simulations of some model and the outcome of the computational experiment will include computational uncertainty. The computational uncertainty depends on the computation technique. The question is, can we add information or parameter into the model on experimental uncertainty from computational uncertainty?

Comment: What is computational uncertainty?

Comment: Computational uncertainty can be using calculus-based relations to advance experimental uncertainty of measurements through the calculations to provide an uncertainty of an unmeasured quantity.  Is this what you mean by computational uncertainty?

Comment: Experimental uncertainty is always addressed using controls and calibrations, i.e. experimental methods. An experienced and careful experimental physicist does not make assumptions about his errors that are only supported by theoretical estimates.

Comment: I may be out of the game, as it were, but I've never noticed anyone using a computational simulation in the midst of an experiment. Usually one does one or the other.